# Maven Archetype dynamic package name

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-archetype

Is it possible to have dynamic package name in maven archetype?? I want to have a dynamic package-name in the archetype(packagename == artifactId) and when I use this archetype for new project then the package name will be as the new artifactId.

Do anyone have idea about that??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found it in other places, so I'll leave here the form I use in my projects:

I use the variable ${groupId} within the classes:

```
package ${groupId}.service;
```

And within the archetype descriptor I add the attribute packaged as true.

```
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
<directory>src/main/java</directory>
<includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
</includes>
```

Another alternative is to use the variable `${package}`, as in the example below: https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-custom-archetype/